# Query SOLR search using id and match documents using different fields

Tags: solr, solr4

In order to describe the problem I will give an example. 
Let's say we have two documents in SOLR,

{id:"0001",
"make":"Ford Focus Diesel"}

{id:"0002",
"make":"Ford Focus ST"}

If the client searches for "Ford Focus ST" I want SOLR to return both documents. 
In other words I want Diesel and ST not to be considered. 
It would also nice if the client searches q=id:0001 and then sorl matches the documents using the title and excluding the words ST or diesel and therefore return both documents.

Any ideas how to customize SOLR to perform like that? Should I implement my own RequestHandler or using a handler that is available? 
I am now looking at the MoreLikeThisHandler

Comment: Your questions are not clear

Comment: I want the on search time SOLR search not to include certain terms. For example "Diesel" in our example. Therefore, when user search using make:Ford Focus Diesel, I want solr to return all the documents that match Ford AND Focus (both documents)

Comment: If you only have a fixed set of such terms to exclude, why not exclude them at index time? Just have a stop filter in your analyzer chain (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory) and add terms like `diesel`, `ST`, etc., to your stopwords file

Comment: There are use cases where these terms might be applicable. E.g you might want to search for Diesel Cars

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Are you trying to exclude the third word of every query?

Comment: Part of the issue is that you're storing `make`, `model`, and `trim` all in one field `make`. And "diesel" could even be a separate field, e.g., `option` (which I would make a **multiValued** field, `options`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are indexing *make* as text (not as strings) then what you are asking for should be happening automatically. In fact a record with *any* of the keywords will match.

If you are trying to match all keywords provided, you could switch to [eDisMax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) query parser and use *mm* parameter to control the percentage of match required.